# Count Points Within X Miles SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with columns store#, latitude, and longitude containing 1,000 stores.  I want the output to have one row for each store with columns 'Within 25 Miles' and 'Within 50 Miles'.

I know how to create the distance between two coordinates, but I need to loop through each store in the table and count how many stores are within 25 miles and how many stores are within 50 miles.

Here is my current code for calculating how far away each store is from a single specified store:

```
DECLARE
@GEO1 GEOGRAPHY,
@LAT VARCHAR(10),
@LONG FLOAT(30),
@STORE VARCHAR(10)

SET @STORE = 1

SET @LAT = (select convert(varchar(10),s.latitude) FROM table s where s.storeNumber = @STORE)
SET @LONG = (select convert(float(30),s.longitude) FROM table s where s.storeNumber = @STORE)

SET @geo1= geography::Point(@LAT, @LONG, 4326)

SELECT s.storeNumber
        , (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(s.latitude,0),ISNULL(s.longitude,0), 4326))) as DISTANCE
FROM table s
```

Comment: Why are `@LAT` and `@LONG` different data types?

Comment: @LONG had negative values and converting it to a float was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: No, that information is not needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.storeNumber
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE 
        (
            (geography::Point(s.latitude, s.longitude, 4326))
                .STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(tbl.latitude,0),ISNULL(tbl.longitude,0), 4326))
        ) / 1609.344 <= 25
     ) cnt_25
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE 
        (
            (geography::Point(s.latitude, s.longitude, 4326))
                .STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(tbl.latitude,0),ISNULL(tbl.longitude,0), 4326))
        ) / 1609.344 <= 50
     ) cnt_50
FROM tbl s
WHERE storeNumber = 1
```

Comment: This is not what I want.  I want the output to be 1000 rows by 3 columns.  Each store row has a count of how many stores are within 25 miles and another count of how many stores are within 50 miles.

Comment: @RyanStodola see the edited post. You don't need to populate a geography variable. You can just recalculate it in-line for each row. Apply your storeNumber filter in the WHERE clause.